# How to create Analog Clock in our app that rotated time to time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, clock

hi I am creating an app in which i need to create a analog clock that showing time of the device and according to the that clock how to get the time of different countries.

So at this point i does not get any idea how to create the clock please any one help me please refer me any tutorial from where i can fetch the clock please....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have already implemented clocks.. You can download it an check how other guys did it or use their classes if you need them..

[ClockView for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/clockview)

[PSAnalogClock for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/psanalogclock)